# Python writing unit tests for decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

```
def mock_registration(func):    
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(obj, car_details):
        if obj.test and car_details.car_name.startswith('test_demo'):
            return 0
        return func(obj, car_details)
    return wrapper
```

That is my decorator. It is used to decorator a class method. What is the best way to unit test this?

I was tempted to create a very simple class with the .test instance attribute in the test_decorator.py file.

```
class Test:
    def __init__():
        self.test = True

    @mock_registration
    def get_registration():
        return 12
```

Then write unit tests that call this Test class.

e.g.

```
car_details = Mock
car_details.car_name = "test_demo test"
assert Test().get_registration(car_details) == 0
```

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Why is your decorator so specific to a certain type of function?

Comment: Because business logic requires it to be.

Comment: I think that the question from @chepner is more along the line of thinking of whether you think that a decorator is the best tool for the job or not. I am not sure how relevant is that for your question, though.

Comment: Yes absolutely is. Has removed a huge amount of redundant code in the code base. I really don't think I should be justifying the use of the decorator. My question is how to test it.

Comment: I'm not sure it's important to test the decorator itself. Do the decorated methods still work as intended? That's the important thing.

Comment: Also, changing the signature of the decorated method is decidedly *not* a good idea. You have to look at the definition of the decorator in order to figure out how to call `get_registration`.